# Which game will I carry over?

Tags: mass-effect-series

In Mass Effect (pretty much many Bioware games) you can import your previous character to the sequel game.

If you start a new game with an existing character in the previous game (and therefore have two characters) which play through/save will be imported into the next game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting a "New Game" with an existing character creates a new save - when you import your character into the next game it loads the latest save for that character meeting the requirements for import (that is, having completed the game).